# How to deploy local source to live server for magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, deployment

I have tried many ways to deploy my local server project to live server or another PC but not working very well.

so please give me a better and exact solution for it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use any automation tool for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing it manually this is the process.

1. Copy whole project to your server machine in the deployment path(probably /var/www/html in linux).
2. Dump your SQL database from your local machine.
3. Create a new database in server and import the dumped SQL file.
4. Change the `base_url` from your database. Update your project URL with new Server accessible URL.

> ```
> UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='http://myserver.com' WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url'
> UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='https://myserver.com' WHERE `path` = 'web/secure/base_url'
> ```

Note: Replace `https://myserver.com` with your server URL.

5. Now Update your app/etc/env.php, change database name, database host, database Username & password with the new ones.
6. Delete all the content from generated/*, var/*, pub/static/*.
7. Set Recursive Write permissions to generated/, var/, pub/static/.
8. Now run these commands.

> ```
> bin/magento setup:upgrade
> bin/magento setup:di:compile
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> ```

Now everything should work properly...!!

Comment: Yeah Thanks! I will this tried but sometime not working well. so is there any specific solutions ? or this is the final one?